# getsockopt: connection refused : Transferring logs from Filebeat to Logstash on other host

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, logstash, filebeat

I'm trying to transfer logs from Filebeat to Logstash

Both are running on different EC2 instances in the same network.
Apparently the socks5 protocol is used instead of http.

This is my filebeat.yml config file

```
filebeat.prospectors:
- type: log
  paths:
    - /camel-logs/app.log
output.logstash:
  hosts: ["remote-host:5044"]
  proxy_url: socks5://10.0.0.10:5044
filebeat.inputs:
- type: log
  paths:
    - /camel-logs/app.log
```

Honestly, I don't really know whether I should use prospectors, inputs, or both here. Neither works for now.

I'm positive that TCP port 5044 between the two hosts is open and accessible, but I don't know if socks5 is even possible over TCP? My knowledge about this stuff is quite limited.

I'm getting this error:

```
pipeline/output.go:74   Failed to connect: dial tcp 10.0.0.10:5044: getsockopt: connection refused
```

This could also be interesting:

```
log/log.go:124  Non-zero metrics in the last 30s        {"monitoring": {"metrics": {"beat":{"cpu":{"system":{"ticks":20,"time":24},"total":{"ticks":40,"time":52,"value":40},"user":{"ticks":20,"time":28}},"info":{"ephemeral_id":"192acef7-0adb-4fbb-adfe-90cade7a5498","uptime":{"ms":30011}},"memstats":{"gc_next":4194304,"memory_alloc":2166616,"memory_total":4100568,"rss":21409792}},"filebeat":{"events":{"active":334,"added":335,"done":1},"harvester":{"open_files":1,"running":1,"started":1}},"libbeat":{"config":{"module":{"running":0}},"output":{"type":"logstash"},"pipeline":{"clients":1,"events":{"active":318,"filtered":17,"published":318,"retry":852,"total":335}}},"registrar":{"states":{"current":1,"update":1},"writes":2},"system":{"cpu":{"cores":2},"load":{"1":3.22,"15":0.47,"5":1.23,"norm":{"1":1.61,"15":0.235,"5":0.615}}}}}}
```

Comment: would you check if 5044 is open for your host `10.0.0.10`?, just type `netstat -ntlp` in terminal and add the output in your question.

Comment: would you be able to add logs from `/var/log/filebeat/filebeat` and `/var/log/logstash/logstash-plain.log` as well

Comment: I've dropped this course for now and have to focus on other things. I will get back to you in a week, thanks @SufiyanGhori